# Changing stackpanel.background using ThemeResources

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

So, I have this Local Brush Resource that i will use for some of my stackpanels and i am wondering how to access it in a c# class. I will be creating stackpanels and i need to set the background to the stackpanel in c#

[image]

In XAML the controls background can be set easily by:

```
Background="{ThemeResource SubPanelBackground}"
```

But i am having trouble finding a way to do it in C# since i will be creating some controls on demand. Here is a code snippet

```
StackPanel Group2Panel = new StackPanel();
Group2Panel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
Group2Panel.Height = 80;
Group2Panel.Margin = new Thickness(10);
Group2Panel.Background = /*Now i cant find what to enter here*/;
```

Can anyone find what i should enter that finds the themeresource brush?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example if the resource dictionary is kept in the same class as the .cs for example page1.xaml and page1.xaml.cs you should use this

```
Brush panelBrush = Resources["SubPanelBackground"] as Brush;
Group2Panel.Background = panelBrush;
```

Or

```
Group2Panel.Background = Resources["SubPanelBackground"] as Brush;
```

But if the resource dictionary is kept in the app.xaml (So it could be used everywhere in the app) you should use this.

```
Brush panelBrush = Application.Current.Resources["SubPanelBackground"] as Brush;
Group2Panel.Background = panelBrush;
```

or

```
Group2Panel.Background = Application.Current.Resources["SubPanelBackground"] as Brush;
```

The only difference is that this one is using Application.Current.Resources

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you can access the resource dictionary from your code:

```
Brush panelBrush = Resources["SubPanelBackground"] as Brush;
Group2Panel.Background = panelBrush
```

Comment: Is there a way to do all of that in one line

also since i will be using a couple different theme resources could you declare multiple themeResources

Comment: @GurfX Group2Panel.Background = Resources["SubPanelBackground"] as Brush <-- is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes that is what i mean, I think the codes both work but then this error happens.

`An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

WinRT information: Cannot find a resource with the given key.

Additional information: Unspecified error`

Comment: "Make sure you can access the resource dictionary from your code" how? details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903952(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: I cant figure out how to access it, can you give me a sample?

Comment: Nevermind i had to use this since my theme resource brush was in the app.xaml `Application.Current.Resources["SubPanelBackGround"];`